# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/AccumulatorParam with spark execution engine on hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Trying to use SPARK as hive execution engine, Getting below error

```
Job failed with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 3 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/AccumulatorParam
    at org.apache.hive.spark.counter.SparkCounterGroup.createCounter(SparkCounterGroup.java:52)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.counter.SparkCounters.createCounter(SparkCounters.java:71)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.counter.SparkCounters.createCounter(SparkCounters.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.RemoteHiveSparkClient$JobStatusJob.call(RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:337)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:358)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

Spark versions : 3.1.1

Hive version : 3.1.2  (also tried with - version2.3.8 got same error though)

Hadoop version  : 3.3.0

Comment: Keep Hive 3.1.2, just use Spark 2.3.4. I tried Spark 3.1.1 and 2.4.8 to the same result, but Hive 3.1.2 and Spark 2.3.4 did the trick... So you might want to try the same thing. Yet I'm not able to answer where is the information showing compatibility of these components.

Comment: Thanks .. Lowering Spark version to 2.4  eliminates this  error..

Comment: @Kaustuv I have same problem but downgrading spark didn't solve my problem. Now it gives Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.spark.counter.SparkCounters. Dow you have any idea?

Comment: Check your Spark- hive compatibility..refer this  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to provide code refactoring, try to find using `org.apache.spark.Accumulator` (deprecated since Spark 2.0.0) and replace it with `org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2`.

UPD: Answering to *Rohit Verma*'s question to be more specific.

```
 1. Change Accumulator with AccumulatorV2.  
 2. Watch the code in your IDE turn red.  
 3. Take a look inside Accumulator, 
    take a look inside AccumulatorV2 
    and see what the difference is.
 4. Provide necessary changes to your code.  
 ...  
 n. Profit!
```

In my case most the changes was like
before: `Accumulator[Int]`
after: `AccumulatorV2[Int, Int]`

Comment: can you be more specific on how to "provide code refactoring"?